# Display RHEL 7.0 Server in Windows Explorer Network List

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, redhat, rhel7, windows-explorer

How can I get my RHEL to simply show up in the network list in Windows Explorer? I have joined my RHEL to my active directory domain successfully. I can also ping and telnet into the machine from any of my machines in the windows AD network, and the computer shows up under the active directory list. I just can't seem to get the machine to display on the network list.

I have downloaded and activated the following packages:
1. telnet
2. samba
3. cifs

Comment: Do you have Samba installed, configured, and running?

Comment: @EEAA: Yes. That is correct. I even rebooted the RHEL server.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was the firewall that caused the problem.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=samba

    firewall-cmd --reload
```

fixed the problem.